# elasticserch nest doesn't seem to have support for boost factor in function scores

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

in the following query, i want to be able to boost the filter by a number. in the query below it's expressed as "boost_factor": 100. this works fine in elasticsearch but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent in Nest. any ideas how to construct this?

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": "_score * doc['somevalue'].value"
          }
        }, 
        {
          "filter": {
            "query":{
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "title": {
                        "type": "phrase_prefix",
                        "query": "some query"
                      }
                    }  
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }, 
          "boost_factor": 100
        }
      ], 
      "query": {
      ...
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

i did find the answer - posting here if someone wants to know. it's due to the different use of multiple function lambdas.

```
s.Query(q => q
.FunctionScore(cfs => cfs
    .Functions(
        fn => fn.ScriptScore(sc => sc.Script("_score * doc['somevalue'].value")),    
        fn => fn
            .BoostFactor(100)
            .Filter(SetFunctionFilters(searchDescriptor)
        )
    )       
    .Query(qy => qy
    ...)
```